# Spanning a row over defined columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My code is as follows, however, "Banks' reaction strategy" should be centered over columns 2 to 4. How can I do that?

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}  %To make professional looking tables
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Long-run effects of a one p.p. increase in the capital requirement (percentage deviation from initial steady state unless indicated)}\label{tab:Angelini1}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\bf{Banks' reaction strategy}} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-4}
    & Fresh capital     & Less dividends    & More profits  \\
\midrule
Output      & 0.00  & -0.05 & -0.36 \\
Inflation       & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  \\
Consumption & 0.00  & -0.08 & -0.29 \\
Investments & 0.00  & 0.08  & -0.82 \\
House prices    & -0.01 & -0.12 & -0.33 \\
\\
Total loans & 0.00  & 0.08  & -1.96 \\
Deposits        & -1.09 & -1.02 & -3.03 \\
Bank capital    & 11.12 & 11.20 & 8.94  \\
Loans to output ratio & 0.01 & 0.14 & -1.60 \\
\\
Loan rates (p.a.) & 0.00    & 0.00  & 0.31  \\
Deposit rates (p.a.) & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  \\
ROE (p.a.)  & -1.23 & -3.07 & 0.00  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item Source: Angelini and Gerali (2012)
\end{tablenotes}
\end{centering}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding your use of `\bf`, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to replace the line:

```
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\bf{Banks' reaction strategy}} \\
```

by:

```
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Banks' reaction strategy}} \\
```

Comment: OMG that was so easy, I forgot that detail! Thanks Miguel, works like a charm now. Best, f

Comment: @Filippo The best way to thank someone for an answer is to accept it, and upvote it.